# Get child nodes as a string

Tags: java, xml, string, nodes

Is it possible to get the child nodes under an XML element/node as a string in Java?

Or do you have iterate through everything?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: it depends what API you're using to access XML.  Many of them have this functionality as a single method call, many don't.  If this is a "killer feature" for you, and it's appropriate, you may wish to consider switching your parsing library if needs be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, like Andrzej said, it depends on the library, For example, jDOM has the useful `XMLOutputter` class that can print to streams, or as a String, or whatever. Most powerful XML libraries will have similar functionality

http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use Transformer:

```
private String nodeToString(Node node) {
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 try {
   Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
   t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
   t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
 } catch (TransformerException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return sw.toString();
}
```